# Laravel active shipping methods

Tags: laravel, model, laravel-models

Table:

```
       Schema::create('shippings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name',64);
            $table->integer('price');
            $table->enum('active', ['yes','no'])->default('yes');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Model:

```
class Shipping extends Model
{
    const YES = 'yes';
    const NO = 'no';

    public function isActive()
    {
        return $this->active == self::YES;
    }
}
```

I wanted to show only active ones by using model function like that

```
 $shipping = Shipping::with('isActive')->get();
```

But then i get

*Error*
*Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on bool*

Am I doing something wrong or is it impossible to make it in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this you can use laravel [scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#local-scopes) Like :

```
class Shipping extends Model
{
    const YES = 'yes';
    const NO = 'no';

    public function scopeActive($query)
    {
        return $query->where('active', '=', self::YES);
    }
}
```

And then

```
$shipping = Shipping::active()->get();
```